# 雪明かり照らす町 . Is there a missing を?

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics, omission

Could someone explain this sentence to me?

> 雪明かり照らす町

Google translates this as:

> The town illuminated by snow

For my part, I would translate it as:

> The town illuminating snow-brightness.

Or

> The town that illuminates snow-brightness.

Note, however, that my translation assumes a を particle has been omitted. Am I on the right track? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is that line from song lyrics?

Comment: Yes. It is from 再会 by Uru.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you think of rewriting this in a different word order as:

```
雪の明かりが町を照らす
```

Does that help?

But 雪明かり is already a word meaning "light of the snow" or "the illumination from the snow".

The idea is that this is a town *which the snow illuminates.*

Comment: +1, It doesn't make much sense to illuminate an illumination, so I think it's more reasonable to think 雪明かり is the subject of 照らす.